# Difference in life of Shri Krishna in Puranas and Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna

An Arya Samaj Influencer Rahul Arya claims that All fake stories have been planted in Srimad Bhagavatam, Skanda Puran and Brahma Vaivarta Puran about Krishna that he is playing with girls, Krishna taking girls' clothes, placing hands on thighs of girls all those activities are fake.

It is done to malign Krishna ji's image .

Krishna ji left Vrindavan at the age of 12 years. How can a kid do such vulgar things with girls.

Please provide answer with accurate reference.

Comment: Too many questions, in one question, is not allowed here. Please check

Comment: too many questions. ask one question per posting.

Comment: All questions are connected