# Puranas (Life of Shri Krishna)

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna

An Arya Samaj Influencer Rahul Arya claims that All fake stories have been planted in Srimad Bhagavatam, Skanda Puran & Brahma Vaivarta Puran about Krishna that he is playing with girls, Krishna taking girls' clothes, placing hands on thighs of girls all those activities are fake.

It is done to malign Krishna ji's image.

Krishna ji left Vrindavan at the age of 12 years. How can a kid do such vulgar things with girls?

Please provide answer with accurate reference.

Comment: how this is diff from https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37629/vedas-and-puranas q?

Comment: Your friend is probably right. Did not remember seeing such stories in Mahabharata proper.

Comment: @Thecrowandthecoconut Mahabharata is the story of Bharata dynasty. Hence it focuses on Kauravas, Pandavas. More on Pandavas because it's Pandavas great grandson asked what their ancestors did. Krishna's life is not the subject of Mahabharata.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Agreed, but Mbh (proper) also makes allusions to Krishna's childhood deeds occasionally. Further, Krishna's words in Gita seem to be contradicting his alleged deeds mentioned in puranas.

Comment: @Thecrowandthecoconut Harivamsha is in fact part of Mbh, in Adi Parva it's Parvas are mentioned with other Parvas..and Harivamsha also mentions few of the above mentioned stories..

Comment: @YDS Yes, that is why I mentioned Mahabharata          **(proper)**. Harivasma is khila.

Comment: @Thecrowandthecoconut Mbh is of 1L shlokas so khila is actually proper bcz after adding it in popular version (like Neelakhantha) we get around 1L shlokas..Mbh is of 100 minor parvas including Harivamsa's..so 100 parvas and 1L shlokas Mbh is proper only..

Comment: Well, Krishna's deeds seems to contradict some of his knowledge given via the bg.